# Creating UIPageViewController with Infinite Scrolling Through Days

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

My app has a journal in it that is controlled by a `UIPageViewController`. The view controller for the page works fine, but the `UIPageViewController` has some erratic behaviour. First, the delegate methods (The page view controller is it's own delegate):

```
private func journalPage(for date: Date) -> JournalViewController? {
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    guard let journalPage = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: JournalViewController.storyboardID) as? JournalViewController else {
        return nil
    }

    journalPage.date = date
    return journalPage
}
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let yesterday = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: self.date) else {
        return nil
    }

    self.date = calendar.startOfDay(for: yesterday)        
    return journalPage(for: self.date)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: self.date) else {
        return nil
    }

    self.date = calendar.startOfDay(for: tomorrow)
    return journalPage(for: self.date)
}
```

I update the `date` of the `UIPageViewController` and then return a configured journal page. The problem is that the there is often duplicate pages (pages for the same date), or a page/date is skipped. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648679/infinite-scroll-uipageviewcontroller) question, but don't see how I can implement something similar.

I've worked with `UIPageViewController` before and have always used an index to get around this, but in this case an index doesn't make sense as you can scroll to the beginning/end of time (literally).

How can I ensure that a new page is made at the correct time to avoid duplicate/missed dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem without using an index (the `date` property on the pages is sufficient). This infinitely scrolls in either direction without creating duplicates or skipping pages.

```
extension JournalPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    /// Creates and returns a JournalViewController if it can be found in the storyboard,
    /// and sets it's date to `date`
    private func journalPage(for date: Date) -> JournalViewController? {
        // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
        guard let journalPage = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: JournalViewController.storyboardID) as? JournalViewController else {
            return nil
        }

        journalPage.date = date
        return journalPage
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        debugPrint("Before: ", separator: "", terminator: "")
        let today = (viewController as! JournalViewController).date
        guard var yesterday = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today) else {
            return nil
        }
        yesterday = calendar.startOfDay(for: yesterday)

        return journalPage(for: yesterday)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        debugPrint("After: ", separator: "", terminator: "")
        let today = (viewController as! JournalViewController).date
        guard var tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today) else {
            return nil
        }
        tomorrow = calendar.startOfDay(for: tomorrow)

        return journalPage(for: tomorrow)
    }
}

extension JournalPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        self.date = (self.viewControllers?.first as! JournalViewController).date
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You must model your data in another way, so create a model containing an array with your data, and (for example) use an index to access dato to fill controller. in this way you uniquely access data.

I did so in a PageController-base app, starting from apple sample.

I have a class: (see apple template to compare..)

class ModelController: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

```
var myPages : [Page]?
```

..
}

where Page is the class describing you single page.
I modified apple code in this way:

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> BaseHWTestController? {
    // Return the data view controller for the given index.

    let count = selected.count
    if (count == 0) || (index >= count) {
        return nil
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.

    let myController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! CustomPageController
    // set ref. to data inside the controller:
    BaseHWTestController.dataObject = myPages[index]
    return BaseHWTestController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the Juilan Day Number (JDN) as an index number?

Comment: I like this idea, but this breaks down when using other calendaring systems does it not?

Comment: iOS lets you easily convert between calendars, so you could use a Juilan date for your index and then map that date to the user's calendar for display.